# What does this If statement do to be exact?

Tags: python-3.x

I was watching a tutorial to make hangman game using Python on YouTube and they used below code in it and didn't explain it.

How does this line work?

```
    word_list = [letter if letter in used_letters else '-' for letter in word]
```

What does that '-' mean/do in this statement?

```
    if user_letter in alphabet - used_letters:
        used_letters.add(user_letter)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What data types are the variables `alphabet` and `used_letters`? They can't be neither strings, nor lists with your syntax

Comment: Both 'alphabet' and 'used_letters' are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line contains a [list comprehenshion](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

It is equivalent to:

```py
word_list = []
for letter in word:
    if letter in used_letters:
        word_list.append(letter)
    else:
        word_list.append('-')
```

The second part:

```py
alphabet = set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
used_letters = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])

alphabet - used_letters  # produces a set: {'d', 'e'}
```